# coercing data frame rows to matrix in R

Tags: r

I'm unsure of better terminology for my question, so forgive me for the long winded approach.

I'm trying to use two identifying variables, `id` and `duration` to fill up the rows of a matrix where the columns denote half hour periods (so there should be 6 for a 3 hour period) and the rows are a given person's activities in those time periods.  If the activities do not fill up the matrix, a dummy variable should be used instead.  I've written an example below which should help clarify.

Example:
data has 3 columns, `id`, `activity`, and `duration`.  id and duration should serve as identifying variables and `activity` should serve as the variable in the matrix.

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
               activity = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "b", "b", "a"), 
               duration = c(60, 30, 90, 45, 30, 15, 60, 100))
```

For the example, I used a 3-hour duration hence the 6 columns in the matrix.  The matrix below is the wanted output.  There are `DUMMY` instances where the total duration of a person's activities does not sum to the duration of the matrix.  In this example, the total duration is 180 (3 hours * 60), so person 2 who's activity duration sums to 75 (45 + 30) will get the `DUMMY` variable after the activities for the first 75 minutes are done.

```
mat <- t(matrix(c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c",
            "d", "d", "e", "DUMMY", "DUMMY", "DUMMY",
            "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a"), 
          nrow = 6, ncol = 3))
colnames(mat) <- c("0", "30", "60", "90", "120", "150")
```

I'm unsure how to fill the matrix `mat` above with the data above.  Any help would be appreciated.  Please let me know if the question needs to be made clearer.

EDIT: edited output

EDIT2: Added matrix column names

EDIT3: Added info on dummy variable

EDIT4: Would it be easier if I added start and end time instead of duration?

Comment: Can you add your desired result?

Comment: I've edited the code above to include the desired result

Comment: The `DUMMY` value is not clear.

Comment: In the absence of the entire time being used by the activities and duration present, I would like to include a dummy variable that indicates a non-activity.  Does that help?

Comment: I updated the post with `dcast`.  Please check if that helps

Answer (score 1):

An approach would be to locate the activities for every 30-min interval by "id":

```
ints = seq(0, by = 30, length.out = 6)

data2 = do.call(rbind, 
            lapply(split(data, data$id),
                   function(d) {
                      dur = d$duration
                      i = findInterval(ints, c(cumsum(c(0, dur[-length(dur)])), sum(dur))) 
                      data.frame(id = d$id[1], ints = ints, activity = d$activity[i])
                    }))
```

And on the new "data.frame":

```
tapply(as.character(data2$activity), data2[c("id", "ints")], identity)
#   ints
#id  0   30  60  90  120 150
#  1 "a" "a" "b" "c" "c" "c"
#  2 "d" "d" "e" NA  NA  NA 
#  3 "b" "b" "b" "a" "a" "a"
```

Comment: That looks like it works.  If instead of duration we had start time and end time as variables would it still work?

Comment: @IJH : In that case, you could utilise the "end" column and `lapply` a simpler function: `...function(d) { i = findInterval(ints, c(0, d$end)); data.frame(id = d$id[1], ints = ints, activity = d$activity[i]) }...`